# Problems with conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I cannot really get (in terms of math steps) from where statement (3) in this setting comes from.

> **Framework:**
>
> - $Y$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed on an interval $[a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$,
> - $y$ is the realization of $Y$ and is **unobservable**,
> - $X_1$ is a signal on $Y$ for the decision maker 1 (DM1),
> - $x_1 := y + \eta$ is the observed signal by DM1, with $\eta$ uniformly distributed on $[-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon]$.

For the following statements, assume a realization of $y$ (as written before, unobservable).

> **Statements:**
>
> 1. DM1's signal is uniformly distributed on $[y -\varepsilon, y +\varepsilon]$.
> 2. Given signal $x_1$, the posterior of DM1 is uniformly distributed on $[x_1 - \varepsilon, x_1 + \varepsilon]$.
> 3. The conditional expectation of $y$ given $x_1$ is equal to $x_1$.

**Thoughts:**

1. It makes sense, indeed both $Y$ and $\eta$ are uniformly distributed. Hence, *a fortiori* $X_1$ is uniformly distributed according to $x_1 := y + \eta$.
2. Once we have a signal $x_1$, we know that $y = x_1 - \eta$, again uniformly distributed, because $y$ is uniform and $\eta$ as well.

> **Problem:** I do not know from where (3) comes from.

Is there somebody who can clarify how we get to that solution?
Of course, I would greatly appreciate any feedback concerning my thoughts on the other statements.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Indeed, typo corrected. ;)

Comment: "uniformly distributed on ℝ" does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To justify statement $(3)$ you only need that $\Bbb E[η]=0$ since $η \sim {\rm U}[-ε,ε]$. Hence, since $x_1:=y+η \implies y=x_1-η$, you have that $$\Bbb E[y\mid x_1]=\Bbb E[x_1-η\mid x_1]=\Bbb E[x_1\mid x_1]-\Bbb E[η]=x_1-0=x_1$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see (I'm a bit ashamed). Just wondering, are my other lines of thoughts correct?

Comment: Again typo. Indeed, you are right.

Comment: Actually (again big fault, I am really sorry), the fact that $Y$ is uniform ss an assumption I forgot to mention. In that case, $X_1$ should be uniform as I mention, I guess.

Comment: Yes, in this case $X_1$ is uniform indeed.